# Why non local return from inline function returns from lambda but proceed inline function execution?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, inline

Can't understand kotlin logic. For sush code

```
inline fun inlined( block: () -> Unit) {
    block()
    
    println("hi!")
}
fun foo() {
    inlined {     
        println("5")
        return@inlined // OK: the lambda is inlined
        println("5")
    }
    println("6")
}
fun main() {
    foo()
}
```

Expected such output "56" but got "5hi!6". How could this happen?
And on my understanfing it contradicts following description from documentation
[image]

Can someone explain it?

UPDATE: Thanks for your answers. I still wandering why execustion of inlined() proceed after calling return@inlined? Anyway lambda is not aware about "inlined()" paremeter "block" but behaves like return@block was called.

Comment: Your sample does not contain a non-local return. By using return@inlined you're actually doing a local return within definition of block() so both inlined and foo functions proceed normally.

Answer (score 5):

You are not doing a non-local return. You are doing a local return, because you used `@inlined`. The local return returns from the lambda, so code execution continues from after `block` was called inside the `inlined()` function. The next line is `println("hi!")`. Then `inlined()` returns and code continues execution inside the `foo()` function.

If you did a non-local return by calling `return` instead of `return@inlined`, then the only thing you would see in the console is `5`. The `println("6")` code would never be reached since you would be directly returning from `foo()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still wandering why execustion of inlined() proceed after calling return@inlined? Anyway lambda is not aware about "inlined()" paremeter "block" but behaves like return@block was called.

Comment: `return@inlined` returns from the lambda function, not from the function that called the lambda. That’s just the way the syntax works. You use the name of the function that you passed the lambda to to return from the lambda, not the name of the function parameter. There’s no call you can make from the lambda to terminate the calling function early. There are several reasons why it wouldn’t make any logical sense to be able to do that.